# Create Table Confusion

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am having some issues / confusion and I am stuck as to where to go from here.

I am experimenting with using Javascript to create tables for my data, and then to display them in HTML. I have created the HTML table without a drama, but the JS one I am having trouble with.

Here is a picture of my expected output:
 [image]

from here, I have the following code to draw the table. However, I can only get up to the 7th row before I get stuck on how to finish the table.

I have read a lot of references and I can not figure out how to do it!

Here is my code so far:

```js
function drawTable3() {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");

  var div = document.getElementById("dropper")

  //create table
  var drawTable = document.createElement("table");
  drawTable.id = "dropperTable";
  drawTable.className = "tg";
  div.appendChild(drawTable);

  var table = document.getElementById("dropperTable"); 

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "D" + [i] + "Size";
  input.type = "number";


  //Create Head Elements
  for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var createHead = document.createElement("th");
    if ( i == 0) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "";
    } else if ( i == 1) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Size";
    } else if ( i == 2) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Capacity";
    }
    table.appendChild(createHead);
  } 

  for ( var i = 1; i < 7 ; i++ ) {

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var dropperName = document.createElement("output");
    dropperName.id = "D" + [i] + "Size";
    dropperName.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Side " + [i];
    cell1.appendChild(dropperName);  

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var dropperInput = document.createElement("input");
    dropperInput.type = "number";
    dropperInput.id = "D" + [i] + "Capacity";
    cell2.appendChild(dropperInput);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var dropperOutput = document.createElement("output");
    dropperOutput.id = "D" + [i] + "Capacity";
    cell3.appendChild(dropperOutput); 

  }

}

drawTable3();
```

```css
.tg  {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0;
 text-align: center;
 }
 
.tg td{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:10px 5px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 text-align: center;
 }
 
.tg th{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:10px 5px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
.tg .tg-s6z2{
 text-align:center
 }
 
.smallInput {
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 }
.roomIdent {

}

.factors {
text-align: center;
width: 80px;
}

.factors2 {
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
}
.tg2 {
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 border-top-color: #FFF;
 border-right-color: #FFF;
 border-bottom-color: #FFF;
 border-left-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropper"></div>
```

Comment: is it that you don't know how to set a cell's `colspan` from JavaScript?

Comment: Hi! No, its not that. I dont know how I can add the other columns / rows to the bottom when outside the FOR loop, then set the colspan and give each the heading / input / output values I require.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What is it about being *inside* the for loop that makes it possible? You've demonstrated that you understand how to create how to create rows and cells in the loop. The only part of that code that uses the loop variable `i` is just to set some `id` attributes and labels. But the remaining rows don't need numbered `id`s and labels anyway. What else is missing?

Comment: Hi, I see that the `var rowCount = table.rows.length;` and `var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);` are missing from the FOR loop. When I add these outside the FOR loop and then use the same `var cell1` etc.. I can create the new cells in the row. But how to I move to the next row?

Comment: you'd just do the `rowCount = ...` and `row = ...` again

Comment: Oh! I didn't think you could do that or just overlooked it, JS is my first programming language so I am still getting the hang of it! Thank you very much, it makes sense. Are there any other tips to help clean up my code?

Comment: Any direction on how to get the `colSpan` working too? I have added `test.colSpan = "2";` to the code, and it does not work.

Comment: You don't need `var table = document.getElementById("dropperTable");`, you already have a reference to the table as *drawTable*, so `var table = drawTable` if you really want to do that.

Comment: Thanks @RobG , So if I create an element using `document.createElement()`, I can actually also use the var to 'get / reference' the element later on? That is a pretty handy trick to save some lines of code!

Comment: All good, I figured out I needed to use `colSpan` to `cell1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments on your code:

```
function drawTable3() {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");
```

*tr* and *td* aren't used anywhere, *input* is re–initialised later.

```
  var div = document.getElementById("dropper")

  //create table
  var drawTable = document.createElement("table");
  drawTable.id = "dropperTable";
  drawTable.className = "tg";
  div.appendChild(drawTable);

  var table = document.getElementById("dropperTable");
```

You already have a reference to the table as *drawTable*, so why not call it *table* from the start? Anyway, the above is equivalent to:

```
  var table = drawTable;
```

.

```
  var input = document.createElement("input");
```

You already created an input above and assigned it to *input*, this replaces it with another input.

```
  input.id = "D" + [i] + "Size";
```

*i* hasn't been assigned a value yet (it's declared lower down so it exists as a variable), so its value is *undefined*. The expression `[i]` will create the array `[undefined]` that is then converted to a string because of the `+` operators and other values in the expression being strings, returning an empty string. So the ID assigned is:

```
'DSize'
```

.
      input.type = "number";

```
  //Create Head Elements
  for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var createHead = document.createElement("th");
    if ( i == 0) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "";
    } else if ( i == 1) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Size";
    } else if ( i == 2) {
      createHead.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Capacity";
    }
    table.appendChild(createHead);
  }
```

The above could be a bit more concise if you use an array for the values and assign them based on the value if *i*. Also, if you are just setting a text value, probably better to insert a text node:

```
  var headCellValues = ['','Dropper Duct Size','Dropper Duct Capacity'];    
  for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var createHead = document.createElement("th");
    createHead.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headCellValues[i]));
    table.appendChild(createHead);
  }
```

.

```
  for ( var i = 1; i < 7 ; i++ ) {

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

This seems to be the only place that *rowCount* is used. To append a row using *insertRow*, provide a value of -1:

```
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

.

```
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var dropperName = document.createElement("output");
    dropperName.id = "D" + [i] + "Size";
```

Here again, `[1]` creates an array that is then converted to a string. Just use *i* to get say "D0Size":

```
    dropperName.id = "D" + i + "Size";
```

.

```
    dropperName.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Side " + [i];
```

Same here, use:

```
    dropperName.innerHTML = "Dropper Duct Side " + i;
    dropperName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Dropper Duct Side " + i));
```

The same should be applied to the rest of the code. You might consider cloning entire rows as it's faster than creating all the elements one by one, or making separate functions to create each type of row. It seems that the header and footer parts can be HTML, and only the intervening rows need to be dynamically created.

```
    cell1.appendChild(dropperName);     

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var dropperInput = document.createElement("input");
    dropperInput.type = "number";
    dropperInput.id = "D" + [i] + "Capacity";
    cell2.appendChild(dropperInput);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var dropperOutput = document.createElement("output");
    dropperOutput.id = "D" + [i] + "Capacity";
    cell3.appendChild(dropperOutput);   
  }
}

drawTable3();
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! This is some great feedback, I have improved my code using the suggestions above and cleaned it up. There was some code that was not being used which I have now deleted. This must have been from trying many ways to get the same result. Thanks Again!

Comment: Also, When I run the code through a validator, There are obviously a lot of redeclaration errors. Should I address these with different variables (instead of i) or is it common practice to change these values?

Comment: Re–declaring variables doesn't hurt, but it might be confusing (e.g. it might indicate an expectation of block scope, which ECMAScript doesn't have). Re–use may also be confusing, e.g. using *i* in two separate loops, consider using say *i*, *j*, *k* etc. for counters.